DISPLAY environment variable not showing up in who command
When I enter "who" as below, only tty2 appears, and the local display does not show up:
team@pc1:~$ who
team  tty2         2024-04-09 15:06 (tty2)
team  pts/0        2024-04-09 15:06 (111.111.111.111)

On other computers, the DISPLAY environment variable value ":0" appeared in the "who" command like below:
team@pc2:~$ who
team  :0           2024-04-09 16:23 (:0)
team  pts/0        2024-04-09 16:23 (111.111.111.111)


I searched for two days without finding an answer, but I just realized the reason. It turns out my Ubuntu display settings were set to Wayland instead of x11 (xorg).
After running sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and commenting out the following line, the system booted into xorg, and afterwards, the DISPLAY value appeared in "who" command.
# WaylandEnable=false

Additionally, other display settings that weren't working were also due to being set to Wayland. I didn't realize that if I'm using Wayland, I should have written the commands based on Wayland.
